# Model is null in controller action after ajaxPost in partial page

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am new to  ASP mvc
I have a partial page like

```
@model IEnumerable<Sample.Models.Privilege>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Details";
}

<script type="text/javascript">
    function UpdatePrivilegeSuccess() {
    }

    function UpdatePrivilegeFailure() {
    }
</script>

<div class="settingsTable" style="position: relative; width: 100%; margin: 0 auto">

    <div style="width: 50%; margin: 0 auto">
        <div style="width: 50%; margin: 0 auto">
            <h2>Privilege</h2>
        </div>
    </div>

    <p>
        @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
    </p>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PrivilegeName)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.module.ModuleName)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.Label("Option")
            </th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>

       @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PrivilegeName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.module.ModuleName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => item.Checked)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.PrivilegeId }) |
                    @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.PrivilegeId })
                </td>
            </tr>
        }

    </table>

    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("UpdatePrivilege", "RolePrivilegemapping",
        new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "PrivilegeWrapper",
                          OnSuccess = "UpdatePrivilegeSuccess",
                          OnFailure = "UpdatePrivilegeFailure"
        }))
    {
         <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Update" />
        </p>
        @Html.ActionLink("Update", "UpdatePrivilege", "RolePrivilegemapping")
    }

</div>
```

I am listing privileges in a table. But after the user click Update for updating model , Model is received as NULL in controller action

```
public ActionResult UpdatePrivilege(IEnumerable<sample.Models.Privilege> updatedPrivilege
{
    return PartialView("_Privilege", One_Track.Models.DataProvider.OneTrackDataProvider.GetPtrackPrivilegeNames());

}
```

Why is this happening? Any help will be appreciated

Comment: The only controls being generated are checkboxes with invalid html (duplicate `id` attributes) and duplicate names (so wont bind to anything) and they are not even inside the form so therefore wont post anything anyway.

Comment: @ Stephen Muecke Ahh I guess Moving everythin inside a form, giving unique Id for checkbox, adding hidden fileds for rest of model will solve the problem

Comment: In addition to those, the most important thing is to use a `for` loop (change the model to `IList<Privilege>`) or use a custom `EditorTemplate` for typeof `Privilege` and in the main view its just `@EditorFor(m => m)` Note both options automatically generate unique `id` and `name` attributes

Comment: Also code such as `@Html.Label("Option")` is a bit pointless. A html `<label>` element is for setting focus to its associated control. Just use `<span>Option</span>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to at least move the data that your posting into your form or nothing will be posted.

You will also need to index your collections so that the modelbinder will work.

This is done by using a `for` loop rather than a `foreach`.

If you need non-editable fields to re-bind you will have to provide them as hidden inputs. You can use `HiddenFor` for this. See them under the `DisplayFor`'s below.

```
        @using (Ajax.BeginForm("UpdatePrivilege", "RolePrivilegemapping",
            new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "PrivilegeWrapper",
                              OnSuccess = "UpdatePrivilegeSuccess",
                              OnFailure = "UpdatePrivilegeFailure"
            }))
        {

       <table>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PrivilegeName)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.module.ModuleName)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.Label("Option")
                </th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>

           @for(var i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => modelItem[0].PrivilegeName)
@Html.HiddenFor(modelItem  => modelItem[0].PrivilegeName)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model[0].ModuleName)
                        @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem  => modelItem[0].ModuleName)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => Model[0].Checked)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.PrivilegeId }) |
                        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.PrivilegeId })
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }

        </table>
             <p>
                <input type="submit" value="Update" />
            </p>
        }
```

Comment: I understand the first point. But sorry to say that i didn't get second point.Am in learning phase and gto the sample from a tutorial.May be I am missing something

Comment: @Robert_Junior Sure no problem, collections is a common thing on here and I'm sure everyone struggles with it at the start. This is a good article. http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/

Comment: thanks a lot for the link.  In tutorials they show foreach for creating the view and i just copied the same

Comment: @Robert_Junior No problem, I tend to use foreach for view only. If posting back then I use a for. :)